# Cassandra 2.1.11 doesn't start in docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra-2.1

Pulling from the official image, cassandra doesn't seems to start and hang the container. Starting a Single node cluster:

```
docker run --name dev-cassandra -d cassandra:2.1
```

Wait for a while to be shure cassandra is started and start a new linked container to run cqlsh

```
> docker run -it --link dev-cassandra:cassandra --rm cassandra:2.1 cqlsh cassandra

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'cassandra':    error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.17.0.2', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

then no way to kill or remove the container (restart of the machine needed)

```
> docker kill dev-cassandra
> docker rm -f dev-cassandra
```

---

The cassandra:latest just work fine

```
> docker run --name latest-cassandra -d cassandra:latest
```

Then waiting for the cassandra to be ready:

```
> docker run -it --link latest-cassandra:cassandra --rm cassandra:latest cqlsh cassandra

Connected to Test Cluster at cassandra:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.0 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

---

My Configuration is:

- Docker (Server Version: 1.9.1, Kernel Version: 4.1.13-boot2docker)
- Yosemite
- VirtualBox 5.0.10

Comment: It works well with docker 1.9.1 on ArchLinux with a 4.2.5-1 kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180 is the active issue that seems to be related to docker 1.9.1 becoming unresponsive on OSX/Windows (via boot2docker) with java processes able to reproduce the problem.